# VS diagnostics pane doesn't match what I see in Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows, ram

When I run my app with F5, the diagnostics pane shows a RAM usage graph that reaches above 2 GB for a period of many seconds.

When I look at the app in Windows' Task Manager, though ("Processes" tab, "Memory" column) it only reaches about 1050 MB.

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: The diagnostics pane doesn't show RAM usage. It monitors *"private bytes"*. Task Manager, by default, shows the *"private working set"*.

Comment: RAM usage is a pretty irrelevant detail on a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  It has to be shared with all the other processes that run on the machine.  So the debugger shows you how much virtual memory your program allocates, the true measure of how much pressure it puts on the machine and a number that doesn't depend on the machine capabilities.  Task Manager shows how much actual RAM is currently mapped to provide the virtual memory.  A bit dated, mattered in the olden days when machines had a lot less RAM and the number was representative of the responsiveness of a program.